# Python web scraping from excel: how to add sleep for every 100 rows

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I am reading links from an excel sheet ("sheet1.xlsx")

Suppose I have columns (ID, Name, Link) and rows from 1 to 100. For example:

```
ID Name Link
1  J    facebook.com/J
2  L    facebook.com/L
.
.
.
.
50 P  facebook.com/P
51 Q  facebook.com/Q
```

My code so far:

```
df1 = pd.read_excel("sheet1.xlsx")
for data in df1.Link :
         print(data)
         result = getResult(driver,data)
```

How can I make this code sleep for 60 minutes everytime it reads 50 links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that helps you

```py
import time

link_counter = 0
df1 = pd.read_excel("sheet1.xlsx")
for data in df1.Link :
    print(data)
    result = getResult(driver,data)
    if  link_counter >= 49: #Check if its the 50th link
        link_counter = 0 #Resets counter
        time.sleep(3600) #Sleeps for 3600 seconds (1 hour)
    else: link_counter += 1 #if statement is false then count one up
```

[but as already said(by Balaji Ambresh) the better solution would be a package like scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237514/13668001)

**Edit**:
that could also work

```py
df1 = pd.read_excel("sheet1.xlsx")
for data in df1.Link :
         if (df1.Link.index(data) + 1) % 50 == 1 and df1.Link.index(data) != 0 : time.sleep(3600)
         print(data)
         result = getResult(driver,data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `time` module for this:

```py
time.sleep(3600) # sleep for 60 minutes.
```

A better solution would be to use a package like [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) to let it handle the throttling.